# How to make popup window fullscreen in Ubuntu microsoft edge broswer?

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, microsoft-edge, fullscreen, popupwindow

I am struggling to make popup window with fullscreen mode in ubuntu edge broswer.
I already have searched a lot however the methods I only found are applicable in Window environment like adding "--kiosk www.top-password.com --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen" to properties.
**Does anyone know how to make popup window fullscreen mode especially in Ubuntu edge broswer..?**

It doesn't matter what browser it is!!
I share my source code that I tried but didn't work in Chrome, Firefox, Edge as below.

```
function popOpen(){
   pop=window.open('https://htmlcodex.com/demo/? item=2463','title','height=' + screen.height + ',width=' + screen.width + 'fullscreen=yes, location=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=1');
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I‘m afraid that you cannot make a popup window in Kiosk mode. But if you enter fullscreen with F11, the popup window works as expected. Do you have any particular need for Kiosk mode?

Comment: @KendrickLi I need the popup window to open with kiosk mode automatically without press F11. Do you know any possible method that I can try...?

Comment: Actually, you can open that popup window in Kiosk mode, but customization is not allowed so it looks just like another normal window. AFAIK, there's no other way to achieve it in Kiosk mode. Hope someone else has a better idea.